# How to calibrate intuitive pointing mechanism

Tags: c++, math, 3d, calibration

I'm trying to implement an intuitive pointing mechanism, where the user would use his hands to just point to an object on-screen. I have most of it ready, except I'm not sure how to write the final part.

Basically, I have a list of calibration points like the following:

```
typdef struct {
    Point2D pointOnScreen, // gives an x/y pixel screen position
    Point3D pointingFinger, // gives the position of the user's pointing finger, in space
    Point3D usersEyes // gives the position of the user's eyes, in space
} CalibrationPoint;

std::vector<CalibrationPoint> calibrationPoints;
```

Now, the idea is that I could use these `calibrationPoints` to write a function that would look something like this:

```
Point2D whereIsTheUserPointing(Point3D pointingFinger, Point3D usersEyes) {
     return the corresponding point on screen; // this would need to be calibrated
                                               // somehow using the calibrationPoints
}
```

But I have trouble figuring out the math of how to do this. The basic idea is that when you're pointing, you're aligning your finger so that `your eyes`-`finger`-`object you're pointing at` are aligned in a straight line. However, since I don't have the position of the screen in 3D, I thought I could instead get the calibration points and deduce where the user is pointing from that. How would I go about writing the `whereIsTheUserPointing()` function and calibrating the system?

Comment: you need distances (z coordinate of the screen)

Comment: @BЈовић: is there no way to do without? I don't have them and there's no easy way to get them. Furthermore the screen is not guaranteeed to be perfectly straight, i.e. the z coordinate could be different for different points of the screen.

Comment: So, that means you need screen's plane parameters, not only it's z coordinate (see [plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29)).

Comment: @BЈовић: yes, but I have no easy way to get them. I'm thinking that the triangulation method pointed out by Kerrek SB might be the best way...

Comment: In that case, it is a wrong approach, and you need to find a different method. Maybe the way touch screen are calibrated

Comment: How many calibration points do you have? Also, do you have multiple calibration points pointing to the same screen position ?

Comment: @LucTouraille: I have no set number of points, I can ask for however many I want, although as little as possible is obviously better for the user.

Comment: Ok, I thought you already had a predefined set of calibration points; if you can perform specific calibrations, then @Kerrek's solution (pointing the four corners from two different locations) is presumably the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm idealizing, but maybe this will be a start:

- I assume that you can obtain universal 3D coordinates for the eyes and the tip of the finger.
- Three points in 3D space span a plane. If we could determine three points on your screen, we could locate the screen plane in 3D space. To be safe, let's locate all four corners, so we don't just know the plane, but also its boundaries.
- Two straight lines in 3D which meet determine a unique point in 3D.

Thus, in order to find the four corners of the screen, produce four pairs of straight lines, two lines through each corner. This could be done by asking the user to point at the four corners, move, and then point at the four corners again.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, although it's a bit more complicated for the user. I'll wait a while to see if there's an easier (for the user) approach.

Comment: @houbysoft: You could demand that the user install a ranging device that lets you read off their distance from the screen. Then you can spare yourself the triangulation, I suppose... Perhaps that's already part of your hardware?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have such a device, and as I've mentioned in other comments, the problem is the screen is not even guaranteed to be straight (i.e. have the same z-coordinate for all of its surface), so I think this might be the only way short of charting the position of the screen by hand. Or maybe I could force the screen to be placed so that the z-coordinate would be the same all over, then perhaps I could use the calibration points to automatically guess the distance.

Comment: @houbysoft: I don't see why you want to take shortcuts for what is essentially a difficult problem. Just triangulate each corner and you've got a robust calibration...

Comment: The goal is to make it as simple as possible for the user. But again yes the triangulation seems like the best way. +1, will accept in a while.

Comment: @houbysoft: you could make the user use a mouse, which is *very* simple :-)

Comment: Isn't it possible to determine the screen position in space using the calibration points? The procedure you give at the end of your answer boils down to collecting special calibration points where the object pointed to is at some specific position on the screen ((0,0), (0,maxy), (maxx,0), (maxx,maxy)); wouldn't it be possible to use the existing calibration points, where the object pointed to is positioned at a random position on the screen? I guess that would imply having at least 3 (x,y) (screen) positions appearing in two or more calibration points, but that does not seem too unlikely.

Comment: Of course, you would not directly obtain the screen boundaries in space then, but wouldn't it be possible to deduce them from the three points (for which we would have both the 2D position on screen and the 3D position in space)?

Comment: Edit: from the three points and the screen resolution (too late for editing the previous comment)

Comment: @LucTouraille: Yeah, calibrating on three known points on your screen (i.e. six measurements) should be enough; having four points may add a little bit of accuracy perhaps.

Comment: Sure, the more points the better. I think that in any cases, the computations should be done in a "fuzzy" manner: there are few chances that two lines obtained from measurement would actually intersect, so @houbysoft should probably consider them as cylinders or something like that.

Comment: @LucTouraille: I'd just go with the closest midpoint between the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Let the co-ordinates of the eyes be (a,b,c) and the coordinates of the end of the finger be (x,y,z). You could easily visualise the joining line in 3D. All you need to do now is to extend the line till it intersects the "plane" of your screen.

Parametric coordinates of the line in your case will be:

```
(a + T(x-a), b + T(y-b), c + T(z-c))

with:

eye at (a,b,c) and finger at (x,y,z).
```

With T = 0, you get the coordinate of the eye. With T=1 you get the coordinate of the end of the finger. You can "extend" the line with T>1.

Assuming you have the z-coordinate of the plane of the screen, you could easily get the value of `T` with the following formula:

```
T = (Z_VALUE_OF_PLANE-c)/(z-c)
```

Substitute this value of T to get the other two coordinates (x,y).

The final co-ordinates on the 2D plane will be:

```
X = a + ((Z_VALUE_OF_PLANE-c)/(z-c))*(x-a)
Y = b + ((Z_VALUE_OF_PLANE-c)/(z-c))*(y-b)
```

Comment: he doesn't have z-coordinate of the screen

Comment: Indeed, if I had the z-coordinate I would know how to do it. But I don't, and perhaps more importantly, the screen is not guaranteed to be straight, so the z-coordinate could be different for different parts of the screen.

Comment: @houbysoft Eye's coordinate and finger's coordinate should be wrt to some origin right? Can you pre-calculate (or put it in a config file or something) the relative placement of the screen wrt to that same origin? About the second part, you would need plane-line intersection...

Comment: @Thrustmaster: in theory, yes, it could be done, but in practice that would not be very convenient (every time you move the setup you'd have to re-measure everything).

Comment: @Thrustmaster: also, it just occured to me that this method does not account for the DPI of the screen, unless I missed something. To be clear, it is NOT guaranteed that the `Point3D`s and `Point2D`s have the same scale. In fact it's more or less guaranteed they have a different scale (Point3D coordinates are in mm, Point2D in pixels).

Comment: About the second part, yes, you would need to convert the 2D coordinate to pixel offsets depending on the screenSize/resolution etc.. I just read Kerrek's solution. May be that is the way to go. :)